# How to search and replace keywords in strings in python from multiple categories?

Tags: python-2.7, replace, text-mining

Assume I have a string which reads:

```
'''
Looking closely we find Pepsi and Coca-cola have been the two two biggest brands of soda in the world for the past four years.
'''
```

and I want to represent mapping of words to its classes as :

```
classes={"NAME":["pepsi","coca-cola", "james","jill"...],"CATEGORY":["soda","food","automobile"....],"NUMBER":["one","two","three","four"....]}
```

So that at the end I want to have the original string as :

```
Looking closely we find NAME and NAME have been the two biggest brands of CATEGORY in the world for the past NUMBER years
```

for a simple dict like :

```
rep = {"NAME": "pepsi", "CATEGORY": "soda"....}
```

I can replace the words for above dict but how do I do that if there more than one word per key?

This is what I have so far:

```
stringh=sentence.lower()

for i,j in rep.items():
    stringh = stringh.replace(j, i)

print stringh
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through the list

```
stringh=sentence.lower()

for i,j in rep.items():
    for k in j:
        stringh = stringh.replace(k, i)

print stringh
```